# Learning Web Development and Game Development at the same time?

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm a junior-level developer, currently working full time and trying to get experience with working with ASP.NET MVC. I love web development, and want to continue to pursue it as my career, but I also love gaming and have done a few game tutorials with Monogame/XNA, and love that as well.

For anyone that has been in this situation, Can you tell me, from experience, if you noticed any form of degenerative results when trying to split focus between a full-time career in another field and beginning game development? I am looking for concrete examples of people who managed to split their time, and what their experience was like. I'm concerned that if I focus on game development on my spare time, then my growth in web development might suffer. I hope to use your input to determine for myself, how I should split up my free time, and manage my "Extracurricular" web projects, AND game development projects, so that I don't end up as a jack of all trades, master of none. I don't know why this is such a hard decision for me. :(

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site.  This question is really off topic for a lot of reasons, I'm sure they will come up in the automatic close vote comments.  You should spend some time reviewing the [help] to try to get a better idea of what makes for a good question.

Comment: As pwny said, it seems off-topic (more of a chat topic, over a virtual coffee). Generally, if you're an X-icist specialized in the A-field of X-ics, then, given the _huge_ knowledge-base we have in the present day, you're unlikely to become a good professional in the B-field of X-ics (although you may be a good amateur). That being said, we all know how well a full-time job and an extra-curricular activity mingle together: the latter will bring you satisfaction, but won't easily grant you popular appraisals. If your passion is gamedev, does it hurt trying to make it a fulltime job?

Comment: Web Development, or at least basic HTML and CSS skills can really help you if you're working on UI systems.

Comment: @SethBattin This is actually on topic based on what I see in the Help Center. (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I would say it falls a bit under Project Management, and mostly under Careers/Game Industry.  That being said, it is a very subjective question, so maybe I could have incorporated some of the tips on good subjective questions to make it better for the Q&A Format. Such as "Ask for actual examples from experience"? Idk, I'm still kind of new to the whole Q&A thing.

Comment: There's a site called Quora that would suit this question much better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is probably off-topic but here's my 2 cents anyways.

Working on what you love, when you feel like it is probably going to yield the best benefits.  By that I mean that if you don't feel like working on a game when you get home but force yourself to do it anyways, you won't grow as much and you'll probably get burned out really quickly.  So work on what you feel like working on.

Also, a lot of people work on unrelated projects in their spare time and make it work.  You don't *need* to do web dev at home as well as during your job to be good at it, although it certainly doesn't harm you in any way.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the skills you learn in one area of programming aren't necessarily exclusive to it.  The concepts you'll learn in either area will definitely be relevant in the other a lot of the time.  For example, Entity systems are used a lot in games but the concepts can be applied to a wide range of applications.

Lastly, give yourself some time.  You don't need to rush to be a guru in something as fast as possible.  Work on what you love and one day you'll realise you know a lot about it and you're not a jack of all trades, master of none anymore.  Not that there's anything wrong with having very broad knowledge, it's actually a desirable skill in the industry!

Comment: Wow, this is a very inspiring answer. I appreciate your response. I too was concerned some would take my question as "off topic" even tho, I am asking a legit question, not discussing "how to get started" or something. Thanks for taking the time to answer. A lot of what you said speaks to me and my actions as a new developer over the past year and a half, and I think I fail to realize my own patterns of thought. Sometimes you need other people to point things out to you to see things clearly, even when you yourself are the subject of discussion.

Comment: @LogicaLInsanity Well it's not a bad question at all, just not that great a fit for the format of this particular site.  I'm glad I could help and I have to say that your capacity for introspection is a rare and important characteristic of a great developper.  Keep it up!

Comment: I would say that this isn't completely off the premise of the site but still quite open ended as a question. However - pwny - this is a fantastic answer so you get my +1